# Do I need transit visa for Switzerland while traveling to Tanzania as Bangladeshi (US permanent resident)?

Tags: transit, transit-visas

I will be traveling to Tanzania on 10 November 2019 and my transit for two hours in Zurich, Switzerland and will be back on 17th

Answer (score 1):

Only citizens of a few countries need transit visa for airside Schengen transfer. Those are: Afghanistan, Bangladesh, Democratic Republic of the Congo
Eritrea, Ethiopia, Ghana, Iran, Iraq, Nigeria, Pakistan, Somalia, Sri Lanka, Syria
and Turkey, and only whey they do not have meet one of the requirements to get an exception of this rule.

Although as a citizen of Bangladesh you'd normally need an airport transit visa, since you are the permanent resident of US, you are exempt from this requirement. See
https://www.eda.admin.ch/countries/usa/en/home/visa/entry-ch/transit.html and https://www.sem.admin.ch/content/dam/data/sem/rechtsgrundlagen/weisungen/visa/bfm/bfm-anh01-liste2-e.pdf

Comment: Beware that each Schengen country has its own additions to the common Schengen list of nationalities that need airport transit visas. They don't all match Switzerland's shown here.